# How to open a pdf in new tab with ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, pdf, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Ques 1: I am working on ngx-extended-pdf-viewer for loading pdf file, but not able to find any ppty to open a pdf in newtab with ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Note: am having pdf as base64 format that's why i picked this wrapper

Ques 2: how to prevent taking print screen (screen shot) of pdf file in ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1: I believe this is what you're looking for: https://pdfviewer.net/extended-pdf-viewer/links

Ad 2: As far as I know, that's not possible. You can suppress printing, but you can't stop anybody from using tools like Greenshot or the Windows Snipping Tool. That's not a restriction of ngx-extended-pdf-viewer. It applies to every browser page (and probably even to almost every application on your machine).